# Python and Labview

Tags: python, labview

I need to call a Python script from Labview, someone know which is the best method to do that?
I've tried `Labpython`, but it is not supported on newest versions of Labview and I'm not able to use it on Labview-2014.
Definitevly, I'm looking for an advice about python integration: I know this two solutions:

1)Labpython: is a good solution but it is obsolete

2)execute python script with `shell_execute` block in Labview. I think that it isn't the best solution because is very hard to get the output of python script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send data from LabView to Python and get back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596974/send-data-from-labview-to-python-and-get-back)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will be useful: 
[send data from LabView to Python and get back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596974/send-data-from-labview-to-python-and-get-back)

Also, the easiest way(for me) to communicate with python code from LabVIEW is to send TCP commands from LabVIEW to Python and back.

Comment: I didn't consider TCP solution, can you give me more information please?

Comment: The idea is to run python script in python ide itself as a server and write LabVIEW client which will send TCP requests to python script and receive response from python.

Comment: Beginning in LabVIEW 2018, there is native support for calling Python modules: http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/python_pal/

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the System Exec.vi in Connectivity->Libraries and Executables menu?

You can execute the script and get the output.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TestScript: a free, source-released Python/LabVIEW connector](https://www.winemantech.com/products/testscript-python-labview-connector). It's fully bi-directional, including arguments and is compatible with LabVIEW 2013 and later, and Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can save Python script as a large string constant(or load from text file) within the LabVIEW vi so that it can be manipulated within LabVIEW and then save that to a text file then execute the Python script using command line in LabVIEW. Python yourscript enter

Answer (score 0):

You can use the integrated Python nodes. There are quite simple examples integrated in LabVIEW. Open them via the Help/Find examples... menu, then type Python into the search field and you will find various Python examples such as "PythonNode_AddTwoDoubles.vi".

Be aware that this Python support is only available with (I think) LV2018 or later.